# the operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Constante

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a sum but i always get that type error .The class OperateurBinair takes two parameters of type Constante , Constante is a class in which i create values (type = double ).

```
public class Plus extends OperateurBinair {

Constante Left;
Constante Right     ;
Constante Somme ; 

Plus() {

    super();
    Left = new Constante();
    Right = new Constante();
    }

Plus(Constante x , Constante y) {

super(x,y);
Left=x;
Right=y;
}

Constante addition() {

    return Left + Right;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Constante` is a reference type. The only reference type for which `+` can be applied is `String`. You want to add the value of their `double` fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
return Left + Right;
```

with

```
return Constante(Left.getter() + Right.getter());
```

Where `getter` is the `getter` method for whatever value you'r actually trying to sum.  This also assumes you have a constructor for `Constante` that takes a `double` argument.  If not, you'll need something more like this:

```
Constante sum = new Constante;
sum.setter(Left.getter() + Right.getter());
return sum;
```

(Or just add a constructor that takes a double.)

Or alternatively, you can add a method to `Constante` to do the summing.

```
public static Constante sum(Constante addend1, Constante addend2) {
    //do whatever logic you want for summing these and return a Constante 
    //with the new value
}
```

Then in the class you're currently working in, you can do:

```
return Constante.sum(Left, Right);
```

Comment: OP may be thinking of C++ and operator overloading

Comment: @Bohemian Well, even so, if he wanted to use the `+ operator` in C++, he'd still have to overload, and he hasn't (tried) doing that here either.

Answer (score 0):

`Constante` is an object and you cannot add objects (with the exception of `String`, which is a special case), because the meaning of that would change from object to object, if it had a meaning at all.

`Constante` may have a method `constante.add(otherConstante)` or if it's your own class you could write one. the `.add()` method would most likely add whatever numberic values are contained within `Constante`.

Alternatively, stop using the class `Constante` and start using a double (or other numeric primitive) if you do not require object behaviour.

#### Other notes

Variable names like `Left` should not start with a capital letter by convention. Classes are in UpperCamelCase, variables are in lowerCamelCase.